# Deleting firehose tracer logs in RabbitMQ

Tags: java, http, logging, rabbitmq, message-queue

I am using the [firehose](https://www.rabbitmq.com/firehose.html) tracer in RabbitMQ.

For this example, I have a queue called Calculator bound to a headers exchange.

To read the logs using a Java client, I am using the HTTP API to read the log files using this code :

```
URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:15672/api/trace-files/calculator.log");

HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

String userpass = "guest" + ":" + "guest";
String basicAuth = "Basic " + javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(userpass.getBytes());

connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", basicAuth);
connection.connect();

BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
```

Problem is, I want to delete the logs right after I read them.
If I delete the log file located in `/var/tmp/rabbitmq/`, The tracing won't work anymore.

Is there a way to delete the log files contents without affecting the tracing process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually works using

```
sudo bash -c "> /var/tmp/rabbitmq-tracing/mylogs.log"
```

Don't now why it didn't work when I deleted it with gedit as a super-user.

Comment: Your bash command truncates the file (removing all file content) rather than actually removing the file. The file still exists after the command but has a length of 0 bytes.